# GitHub Advanced Security for Azure DevOps - Dependency Scanning and CodeQL for a C# application using Docker@2 build failing to find code

Tags: azure-devops, github-advanced-security

GitHub Advanced Security for Azure DevOps - Dependency Scanning and CodeQL for a C# application built using `task: Docker@2` failing to find code but similar pipeline works for JS.

I’ve got two applications built using the `Docker@2` built setups and using GHAS in ADO to scan the code.

The JS based one works OK and both Dependency Scanning and CodeQL return results. But the C# one gives the following error:

```
CodeQL detected code written in C# but could not process any of it. This can occur if the specified build commands failed to compile or process any code.

- Confirm that there is some source code for the specified language in the project.

- For codebases written in Go, JavaScript, TypeScript, and Python, do not specify an explicit --command.

- For other languages, the --command must specify a "clean" build which compiles all the source code files without reusing existing build artefacts.

##[warning] Error running the 'database finalize' CodeQL command (32)

##[error]Error running the 'database finalize' CodeQL command (32)

Learn more about the scan for the CodeQL build tasks:
```

Pipeline for the C# one

```
# Advanced Security Initialize CodeQL v1
# Initializes the CodeQL database in preparation for building.
- task: AdvancedSecurity-Codeql-Init@1
  inputs:
    languages: 'csharp'
    querysuite: 'security-and-quality'

- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Login To Azure Container Registry
  inputs:
    command: login
    containerRegistry: ${{ parameters.ContainerRegistryServiceConnection }}

- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build Build Docker Image
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: ${{ parameters.ContainerRegistryServiceConnection }}
    repository: ${{ parameters.ImageRepository }}
    command: "build"
    Dockerfile: ${{ parameters.DockerfilePath }}
    buildContext: "."
    tags: |
      $(Build.BuildId)
      latest

# Advanced Security Dependency Scanning v1
# Scan for open source dependency vulnerabilities in your source code.
- task: AdvancedSecurity-Dependency-Scanning@1
  displayName: Dependency Scanning

# Advanced Security Perform CodeQL analysis v1
# Finalizes the CodeQL database and runs the analysis queries.
- task: AdvancedSecurity-Codeql-Analyze@1
  displayName: Perform CodeQL analysis
```

We've split the docker build and publish tasks to match the JS application that works but the C# fails to find the code.

Comment: Hi Paul, does your JS code also build with the `docker@2` task?     I found this [Running CodeQL code scanning in a container](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/code-scanning/creating-an-advanced-setup-for-code-scanning/running-codeql-code-scanning-in-a-container), it mentions _You must run CodeQL inside the container in which you build your code. This applies whether you are using the CodeQL CLI or GitHub Actions._   Maybe it is same in Azure DevOps. By the way, you can set the loglevel to 2 in the `AdvancedSecurity-Codeql-Init@1` task to check more information in the logs.

Comment: yes the working JS one does use the docker@2 task (pretty much the same but some extra parameters on the build command) I'd seen the  Running CodeQL code scanning in a container post but wasn't sure how to apply that advice to ADO as it had specific syntax for github actions. I'll try the loglevel 2 again on both repos and see what we get

Comment: Hi Paul, in ADO, there is also a container job. You can refer the [container jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops) for more information.